# Unhandled Exception: System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write 

Tags: c#, c++, dll, dllimport, dllexport

Below is my c++ DLL

```
// DLL.cpp : Defines the exported functions for the DLL application.
#include "stdafx.h"
//#include <stdexcept> 
#include<iostream>
using namespace std; 

typedef void (*FunctionPtr)(int); 
void (*FunctionPtr1)(int); 
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)void Caller();
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)void RegisterFunction(FunctionPtr func_ptr); 


    extern void Caller() 
    {    

        int i = 10;
        FunctionPtr1(i);
 } 

    extern void RegisterFunction(FunctionPtr func_ptr1)
 {
     FunctionPtr1 = func_ptr1;

 }
```

This DLL will get refernce to function name from c# and pass arguments to c# function..
here is my c# code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;



namespace test
{
    class Program
    {

        [DllImport("C:/Users/10602857/Documents/Visual Studio 2010/Projects/DLL/Debug/DLL.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern void Caller();

       [DllImport("C:/Users/10602857/Documents/Visual Studio 2010/Projects/DLL/Debug/DLL.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern fPointer  RegisterFunction(fPointer aa);

        static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                    Console.WriteLine("DLL Linking");
                    fPointer abc = new fPointer(ping);
                    RegisterFunction(abc);      //send address of function to DLL
                    Caller();                   //call from DLL
            }

        public  delegate void fPointer(int s);       // point to every functions that it has void as return value and with no input parameter 


        public static void ping(int a)
             {
                     Console.WriteLine("ping executed " + a);
             }

        public static void add1()
              {
                      Console.WriteLine("add executed");
              }

    }
}
```

c# code is able to get the value which i paseed in c++  dll as below

```
int i = 10;
        FunctionPtr1(i);
```

M getting the sedired output but progrram got crashed at the end with following execption

```
Unhandled Exception: System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write
 protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
   at test.Program.Caller()
```

why i am getting this ??

Comment: What about wrap C++ dll using C++/CLI? As my experience, this is much easier!

Comment: i am new to this..how can i implement it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All i need to do is..
just declare my delegate as ...

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)] 
public delegate void MyDelegate();
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I wrote test code for you.
Concept is simple.

1. You wrote dll using C++ or C.
2. CLR library(Managed dll) wraps your dll.
3. Your C# code can use your Native DLL via CLR library.

Your Native DLL

**MyDll.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include<iostream>
using namespace std; 

typedef void (*FunctionPtr)(int); 
void (*FunctionPtr1)(int); 
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)void Caller();
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)void RegisterFunction(FunctionPtr func_ptr); 


extern void Caller() 
{    
    int i = 10;
    FunctionPtr1(i);
} 

extern void RegisterFunction(FunctionPtr func_ptr1)
{
    FunctionPtr1 = func_ptr1;
}
```

Your CLR library, wrapper for Native Dll

**MyDllCLR.h**

```
#pragma once

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;

typedef void (*FunctionPtr2)(int); 
extern "C" __declspec(dllimport)void Caller();
extern "C" __declspec(dllimport)void RegisterFunction(FunctionPtr2 func_ptr); 

namespace MyDllCLR {

    void MyFunc(int i);

    public ref class Class
    {        
    public:
        delegate void FunctionDelegate(int i);
        static FunctionDelegate^ fun;

        static void Caller1()
        {
            Caller();
        }

        static void RegisterFunction1(FunctionDelegate^ f)
        {
            fun = f; // Wrapper MyFunc call this delegate

            // this occurs runtime error and I don't know why.
            // So I wrote Warpper MyFunc() method. I usually do like this.
            //IntPtr p = Marshal::GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(fun);
            //RegisterFunction((FunctionPtr2)(void*)p);

            // Register Function Wrapper instead of user delegate.
            RegisterFunction(MyFunc);
        }
    };    
}
```

**MyDllCLR.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "MyDllCLR.h"

void MyDllCLR::MyFunc(int i)
{
    MyDllCLR::Class::fun(i);
}
```

Your C# code using Native DLL

**Program.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace TestMyDllCLR
{
    class Program
    {
        static void MyFunc(int i)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Come on! {0}", i);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyDllCLR.Class.RegisterFunction1(MyFunc);
            MyDllCLR.Class.Caller1();
        }
    }
}
```

You need Native DLL and CLR DLL both for Program.cs

And, of course, this is not the only way for your goal. :)

Comment: - your concept is nice...
but i tried declaring my delegate as 
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)] 
public delegate void MyDelegate(); 
its working fine now :)

Answer (score 0):

It could well be that your delegate

```
fPointer abc = new fPointer(ping);
```

is getting garbage collected before it's being used.
You need to store the reference to the delegate as a field of the class to ensure it survives for the lifetime of the class.

Try defining `fPointer abc` outside `main` then assign `new fPointer(ping)` to it inside `main` and see if that helps.

Comment: Hmm, are you sure the calling convention is correct? Have you tried stdcall rather than cdecl? Although I presume the C in the C++ code indicates cdecl so it's a stab in the dark. Is the copying to FunctionPtr1 necessary is this the equivalent of changing the type?

Comment: You could also try adding the `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)]` attribute to the parameter in your RegisterFunction dllimport statement. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7esfatk4.aspx